# Is ecchi used for humor or is it sexually playful?

Tags: terminology

The definition of ecchi is sexually playful, right? But I heard it is almost always used for humor. Can someone explain please?

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Ecchi

Comment: Well.....there is humor that is sexually playful right, just watch Sekirei or......Photon  Ecchi can be funny,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecchi) the definition of ecchi is:

> Ecchi (エッチ etchi?, pronounced [et.tɕi]) is an often used slang term in the Japanese language for **playfully sexual actions**. As an adjective, it is used with the meaning of "sexy", "dirty" or "naughty"; as a verb, ecchi suru (エッチする), with the meaning to have sex; or as a noun, to describe someone that is seen as lecherous. It is perhaps softer than the Japanese word ero (エロ　from Eros), and does not imply perversion in the way hentai does.
>
> The word ecchi has been adopted by fans of Japanese media to describe works with sexual overtones. I**n Japanese, the word ecchi is often used to describe a person's conduct, but in fandom, it has come to be used to refer to softcore or playful sexuality**, as distinct from the word hentai, which connotes perversion or fetishism. **Works described as ecchi do not show sexual intercourse or genitalia, but sexual themes are referenced.** Ecchi themes are a type of fan service, and can be found in most comedy shōnen and seinen manga and harem anime.

This imply's that it can be used for a number of situations including those that are humorous or sexually playful.